Drawing Internal Lines in a polygon using C# Unity
I've got a video link which I hope describes this correctly.
This is for Dijkstra's, and I have created a polygon. Working in Unity the polygon will be a polygonCollider2d. I would now like to know what points can see the other points on the polygon internally. If I could just find a link to a tutorial or a paper or something I could figure it out. But going search after search has gotten me nowhere. Another post was suggested but that one was only to output a boolean finding out if a shape of convex or concave. My problem is to find every internal vertex connection for each vertex. Hopefully the addition of this third image will explain it. I've tried shooting rays and using colliders but can't figure out the right combination. Maybe it can be just pure math and I don't need to do any raycasting. When doing a Dijkstra's problem usually the neighbours to each node are already given. My problem is having a shape where the neighbours are NOT given and I have to find them.
This video is me asking for help but the answer below has an explanation on how I chose to do it.
Youtube Video




This question is similar to: How do I efficiently determine if a polygon is convex, non-convex or complex?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this, or this. For both you just have the specialised case that the point is at one of the vertices each time

I will go through these to see how it is done with pure math. So far i have something working using raycasting and edge colliders.

If you got it working (as it seems you have by your edits), you should post those edits as an answer instead. That way people browsing the site know you've resolved your issue.

Videos Below
I have played around a bit more and got something working. I tried an equation I found online to detect if two segments cross, but it was a bit buggy, so I went back to shooting raycasting and I've actually got it working now.

Ok. I found some better math for the intersection, and it ran faster than using physics2d and now everything works. The calculation time is 0.0002s well under a frame. I did a polygon with 60 points and still got about 0.002s which is still under a frame but would like to get it lower

Youtube videos.
Explanation YouTube video
Math and Programming
